# Title in Settings bundle not showing in the Settings

Tags: ios, xcode6, settings.bundle

I've pasted a screen shot. The text Area is visible but the title is not showing up in the settings page. I couldn't figure it out.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

I found that I needed four fields active and filled out for it to show up properly.

**Type:** Title

**Title:** Whatever

**Identifier:** what_ever

**Default Value:** [okay to leave blank]

Comment: This! I was missing the Default Value. Once I added it it appeared

Comment: Was having it active all you needed or did you have to fill it in?

Comment: Not sure, because I filled it in either way

Answer (score 6):

You just need to add a new row, under your Default Value with the key "Identifier". It should works ;)

UPDATE 1:

I've tested with a swift project, and all works fine:

[image]

Next, my code in the AppDelegate:

[image]

Finally, the result in the simulator:

[image]

Comment: I've tried that too. Neither the default value nor the assigned value showed up.

Comment: Did you write some code in your app to change de Default Value or something like that ?

Comment: Yes, did that in the appDelegate didFinishLaunching. Did you try with a Swift project?

Comment: No, I didn't. I tried in an Objective-C project. Could please show me the part of code where you are dealing with your Settings Bundle ?

Comment: Yes, in the app delegate I'm setting the value. Even the default value is not appearing. Is "Title Field" not available in Swift?

Comment: Are you sure you set a non-nill string for your Title in your app delegate ?